# Navigation framework in silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, navigation-framework

In silverlight navigation framework how to navigate to a xaml page from mainpage.xaml ? In my scenario i have  menu items and need to go to corresponding menu item's xaml page on menu click.

Comment: Did you try using NavigationService.Navigate("AnotherPage.xaml",UriKind.AbsoluteOrRelative); call ?

Comment: i'm adding the menu item in a usercontrol page. so i'm not getting NavigationService.Navigate MEthod at all..

Comment: Hmm I see.. Within the user control, Add reference to System.Windows.Navigation and try. What you want to accomplish is on MenuClick you can fire Navigate Call to appropriate Xaml.

Comment: i tried adding the reference but still i'm not able to navigate. i'm not getting NavigationService.Navigate method in xaml pages which are of type usercontrol. Ex:-<UserControl x:Class="MainPage"> . In xaml navigation pages (<navigation:Page x:Class="ABC">) i'm able to navigate to other xaml pages through NavigationService.Navigate method.

Comment: Within the XAML of UserControl try adding a XAML namespace for System.Windows.Navigation e.g. xmlns:NavTo="CLR-.......,System.Windows.Navigation". Then you can use the NavTo Tag to refer to the Url on Menu Click events.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a NavigationService variable on startup in your App.xaml.cs file. Assign the variable the first time you visit the page hosting the navigationframe - you get the NavigationService from the frame control.

In you menu usercontrol you can access the NavigationService in the App namespace:
((MyApp)App).NavigationService

Answer (score 1):

Solution :- 
In xaml pages which are of type usercontrols the navigation can be carried out by adding navigation frames in xaml page.

Ex:- 
**Xaml Page**

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}" 
                              Source="/Home" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
                <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
                </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            </navigation:Frame>
```

**In .cs page**

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("URIPATH", UriKind.Relative));
```

// where URIPATH is the class to which the navigation is required